# SQL Server Insert rows from a table into another table with null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, rows, nopcommerce

Ok so I have just created a table `_amazonProduct` with some columns:

```
ID
ProductID
ProductPrice
```

Now I have a product table with many columns, more than 50.

The column I want to insert is `Id` from `product` table into `ProductID` in `_amazonProduct`. All other values will be set to null.

Some things I have tried.

```
UPDATE [Azure_Test].[dbo].[_amazonProduct]
SET [Azure_Test].[dbo].[_amazonProduct].[ProductID] = [Azure_Test].[dbo].[Product].[Id]
FROM [Azure_Test].[dbo].[_amazonProduct]
JOIN [Azure_Test].[dbo].[Product] ON [Azure_Test].[dbo].[_amazonProduct].[ProductID] = [Azure_Test].[dbo].[Product].[Id]
```

Also tried:

```
SELECT [Azure_Test].[dbo].[Product].[Id]
INTO [Azure_Test].[dbo].[_amazonProduct].[ProductID]
FROM [Azure_Test].[dbo].[Product]
```

Also tried:

```
UPDATE [Azure_Test].[dbo].[_amazonProduct]
SET [ProductID] = (
    SELECT [Id]
    FROM [Azure_Test].[dbo].[Product]
)
```

Anyone able to help me out, not sure exactly how to go about this.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try：
  --Copy strtuct:

```
SELECT *
INTO [Azure_Test].[dbo].[_amazonProduct]
FROM [Azure_Test].[dbo].[Product] WHERE 1=0
GO
sp_rename '_amazonProduct.ID','ProductID','COLUMN'
GO
```

--Insert into new table:

```
insert into [Azure_Test].[dbo].[_amazonProduct](ProductID)
 select ID FROM [Azure_Test].[dbo].[Product]
```

Also you ca use dynamic script。

Comment: Perfect the second statement is exactly what I needed, it inserted each ProductID, auto incremented the ID and sett other values to null. Thanks for the help champ :)